# Expected number of regions with $n$ random lines in a circle

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

There are $n$ random lines drawn in a circle, defined by endpoints being uniform on circle. I am trying to figure out the expected number of regions separated by $n$ lines. I know $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=\frac{10}{3}$. Though naive, I can work it out through enumeration. But when $n$ is large, is there a formula to do this?

Comment: Suppose there are $L$ lines, and they intersect at $P$ different points.  (We assume no $3$ lines meet at the same point.)  From various small examples it seems the number of regions would be $R= 1+L+P$.  Can someone confirm this?  It seems some smart induction proof might work, but I can't quite make it rigorous enough and that leaves me doubtful.  Anyway, if true, this may provide a way to find $E[R]$ by finding $E[P]$.

Comment: It seems to me that it will matter how the lines are randomly drawn. Are they drawn through two random points on the circle? Are they drawn with a random point and angle? This is a well known statistical [paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)). I'm not sure it will apply here since the problem is slightly different, but it seems like it will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Euler's formula states that, for any planar graph, $f - e + v = 2$, where $f$ is the number of faces (what you call regions, with an important caveat to be discussed at the end of this post), $e$ is the number of edges, and $v$ is the number of vertices.

Each line necessarily intersects the circle at exactly $2$ distinct points (the case of a tangent line happens with probability $0$, and the case of no intersections is not relevant). If, in addition, there are $P$ points of intersection, then $v = 2L + P$, where $L$ is the number of lines.

It happens with probability $0$ that any point $P$ lies at the intersection of more than $2$ lines or that any vertex on the edge of the circle is at the intersection of more than $1$ line with the circumference. Thus, there are exactly $4$ edges meeting at each of the $P$ intersection points and exactly $3$ edges ($2$ circular arcs and $1$ edge corresponding to a line) meeting at each of the $2L$ circumference points. Thus, we might guess $e = 3(2L) + 4(P)$. But this actually double counts, since each edge is connected to exactly $2$ different vertices. Thus, we must divide by $2$ to get the true number of edges $e = 3L + 2P$.

Putting this all together, we find
$$
f - (3L + 2P) + (2L + P) = 2
$$
That is
$$
f - L - P = 2
$$
Or
$$
f = 2 + P + L
$$
You might wonder why we have $2$ instead of $1$ in this last expression. That is because the exterior of the graph counts as a face for Euler's formula. That is, we have overcounted by $1$. Therefore, the number of regions is given by
$$
R = 1 + P + L
$$
as you suspected.

The only remaining question is how to assign a probability to $P$. As I mentioned in my first comment, my guess is that this will be impossible without more precisely defining how you will be randomizing your lines.

Comment: +1 nice rigorous justification of $R=1+P+L$ via the observation that it depends on exactly $4$ edges meeting at an internal intersection and exactly $3$ meeting at an intersection with the circle, both happening with probability $1$.

Comment: re: how the lines are randomized, the OP did say "endpoints being uniform on circle" (at least, as of 2019/10/9).  what the OP didn't explicitly say is that the two endpoints of a line are independent, but i thought that was meant implicitly - just as endpoints of different lines are clearly meant to be independent.  so IMHO Bertrand's paradox didnt apply because the OP specified the distribution was variation no.1 of the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)).  hence the permutation argument applies and any two lines intersect with prob $1/3$.

Comment: I've actually never seen a proof that the probability of intersection is $\frac{1}{3}$, but now I have a fun little homework assignment. Assuming the probability is $\frac{1}{3}$, it still isn't completely clear to me that $E(P(L)) = \frac{C^2_L}{3}$, but probability has never been my strong suit.

Comment: since you said homework, i wont give it away.  if you want an explanation at a future date, just @antkam msg me again!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint from antkam, With $L$ lines intersecting $P$ points, we have number of regions at $R=1+L+P$. $E(P(L))$ can be calculated by linearity of expectation, which means for any two lines, there is $\frac{1}{3}$ probability that they intersect and we have $C^2_L$ combinations. So, $E(R(L))=1+L+\frac{C^2_L}{3}$.

Comment: I am 99.9% sure $R=1+L+P$, in which case the rest of your argument is of course valid.  However, I just couldnt remove all doubts...  Do you see a quick proof that $R = 1+L+P$?

Comment: You might find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Plane_graphs) helpful.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins - oh of course!!  :)  Euler characteristic...  how did i _not_ think of that?

Comment: Your problem closely resembles [this](http://www.arbelos.co.uk/Papers/Chords-regions.pdf) relatively famous problem (unfortunately I can't find the name of it right now), whose solution also makes use of the Euler characteristic. I've been thinking about this problem on and off since I saw it, and I haven't figured out a way to quantify the number of edges given the number of intersections and lines. Hopefully you can come up with a rigorous argument.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins - oh yeah, the famous [sequence that starts with 1,2,4,8,16,_31_...](https://oeis.org/A000127) :)